# Putting Numeric and string value in B2 and C2 cells based on A2 cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a dropdown list where if you select a certain employee ID in cell `"A2"` it fills out cell `"B2"` with the three digit employee numeric id and `"C2"` with the full employee name. It should be a fairly simple task, however the code I wrote doesn't work whatsoever. After I run it it puts a `"0"` in `"B2"` regardless of the selection in `"A2"` and nothing in `"C2"`. I tried to juggle around with `.Value/.Text/.Number` identifiers, and using `""` or no `""` around the values to no avail. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub ind_naming()
Dim in_ws As Worksheet
Set in_ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("INDIVIDUAL_REPORT")

in_ws.Range("A5:E100").Delete Shift:=xlUp
in_ws.Range("A5:E100").Interior.Color = RGB(224, 245, 250)

in_ws.Range("F1").Value = in_ws.Range("A2").Value

If in_ws.Range("A2").Value = "BI08298" Then in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "113" And in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "John Smith"
If in_ws.Range("A2").Value = "GB31446" Then in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "170" And in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "John Bob"
If in_ws.Range("A2").Value = "ZB40049" Then in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "158" And in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "Gary Doe"
If in_ws.Range("A2").Value = "KF14006" Then in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "121" And in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "Mary Jane"
If in_ws.Range("A2").Value = "JT99623" Then in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "167" And in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "Nate Tailor"
If in_ws.Range("A2").Value = "FO07386" Then in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "168" And in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "Jacob Grant"


End Sub
```

Comment: You could also do this with a dropdown in A2, and `VLOOKUP` in `B2` and `C2` referencing a table containing the data.

Comment: I've tried VLOOKUP but it doesn't work, even though the syntax is correct.

Comment: If the syntax is correct, and the values are identical, `VLOOKUP` will work.  But you provide no information to help you solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use Vlookup. I guess you have (or you should have) table somewhere, let say in sheet names "Emps". This table should be like:

```
Emp_ID    Emp_Number    Emp_Name
BI08298   113           John Smith
```

Then you can put following formula into B2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Emps!A:C, 2, 0),"")
```

and in C2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Emps!A:C, 3, 0),"")
```

Formulas may be inserted via VBA as well. I would make a macro under the worksheet (not in the module), something like that;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$A$2" Then Exit Sub

    Dim sFormulaB As String, sFormulaC As String
    sFormulaB = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Emps!A:C,2, 0),"""")"
    sFormulaC = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Emps!A:C, 3, 0),"""")"

    With Target
        .Offset(, 1).Formula = sFormulaB
        .Offset(, 2).Formula = sFormulaC
    End With

    Call RestOfCode_procedure
End Sub
```

You can store the rest of code in your sub in normal module and call it from the procedure above.

Comment: I've tried `VLOOKUP` but it doesn't work for me. I have a dropdown with the employee IDs in sheet `"INDIVIDUAL_REPORT"` Cell `A2`, and it references the list on the sheet `"REVIEWERS"` Range `"A2:A8"`. I have the employee's numeric id in `REVIEWERS` Range `"B2:B8"` and the full name in `REVIEWERS "C2:C8"`. I have the following formula on the `"INDIVIDUAL_REPORT"` sheet cell `"B2"`: `=VLOOKUP(A2,REVIEWERS!A2:A8,2,FALSE)` but it just puts `!REF#`

Comment: Yep just tried pasting your proposed VLOOKUP formulas, switched the column and the sheet name with the data and it works perfectly now. Thank you! I use VBA 99% of the time, while I barely know anything about formulas, but this is a much more elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with a Case statement, but I would probably go for a Vlookup with all the details of the Employee in a separate Sheet that you can look up against, this way you will reduce your lines of code and if any details on that sheet change, so would your code, but for the Case statement see below:

```
Sub ind_naming()
Dim in_ws As Worksheet
Set in_ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("INDIVIDUAL_REPORT")

in_ws.Range("A5:E100").Delete Shift:=xlUp
in_ws.Range("A5:E100").Interior.Color = RGB(224, 245, 250)

in_ws.Range("F1").Value = in_ws.Range("A2").Value

Select Case in_ws.Range("A2").Value
    Case "BI08298"
        in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "113"
        in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "John Smith"
    Case "GB31146"
        in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "170"
        in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "John Bob"
    Case "ZB40049"
        in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "158"
        in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "Gary Doe"
    Case "KF14006"
        in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "121"
        in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "Mary Jane"
    Case "JT99623"
        in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "167"
        in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "Nate Tailor"
    Case "FO07386"
        in_ws.Range("B2").Value = "168"
        in_ws.Range("C2").Value = "Jacob Grant"
End Select

End Sub
```